# Commutators of tensor product of Pauli matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, tensor-products

Given tensor product of rank-2 Pauli matrices $\sigma^a$. Each $\sigma^a$ is related to the generator of SU(2) Lie algebra.

We know they satisfy

$$[\sigma^a, \sigma^b ] = 2 i \epsilon^{abc} \sigma^c$$

Do you know any equality/identity to simplify:
$$
[\sigma^a \otimes \sigma^c, \sigma^b \otimes \sigma^d] = ?
$$
also
$$
[\sigma^a \otimes \sigma^c  \otimes \sigma^e, \sigma^b \otimes \sigma^d  \otimes \sigma^f] = ?
$$
$$
[\sigma^a \otimes \sigma^c  \otimes \sigma^e \otimes \sigma^g, \sigma^b \otimes \sigma^d  \otimes \sigma^f \otimes \sigma^h] = ?
$$
so that the final answers have no commutators?

Commutator is defined by default as
$$
[A,B]:=AB-BA
$$

Comment: just to be precise, I think your tensor product here also means the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: There is no reason to expect anything nice for those formulas. The reason is that the tensor product of lie algebras is not a lie algebra in any sensible way.

Comment: Supposedly always either the commutator or the anticommutator is zero (unfortunately I only read the result without proof)

Answer (score 13):

If you check out [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) you will see that it has the mixed-product property:

$$
(\mathbf {A} \otimes \mathbf {B} )(\mathbf {C} \otimes \mathbf {D} )=(\mathbf {AC} )\otimes (\mathbf {BD} ).
$$

Using this property and the fact that
$$
\sigma^a\sigma^b = \delta_{ab}I+i\epsilon_{abc}\sigma^c
$$
you can expand the product $(\sigma^a \otimes \sigma^c)(\sigma^b \otimes \sigma^d)$ as

\begin{align}
(\sigma^a \otimes \sigma^c)(\sigma^b \otimes \sigma^d) 
&= (\sigma^a\sigma^b)\otimes(\sigma^c\sigma^d) \\ &= (\delta_{ab}I+i\epsilon_{abe}\sigma^e)\otimes(\delta_{cd}I+i\epsilon_{cdf}\sigma^f) \\
&=\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}I+i\epsilon_{abe}\delta_{cd}(\sigma^e\otimes I)+i\epsilon_{cdf}\delta_{ab}(I \otimes \sigma^f)-\epsilon_{abe}\epsilon_{cdf}(\sigma^e\otimes\sigma^f).
\end{align}

Since the first and last terms in this expression are symmetric when the indices $ab$ and $cd$ are permuted, the first commutator you ask for simplifies to

$$
[\sigma^a \otimes \sigma^c, \sigma^b \otimes \sigma^d] = 2i\epsilon_{abe}\delta_{cd}(\sigma^e\otimes I)+2i\epsilon_{cdf}\delta_{ab}(I \otimes \sigma^f).
$$

Note that the two terms are mutually exclusive since if $\delta_{cd}=1$, then $\epsilon_{cdf}=0$, and likewise for the pair of indices $ab$.

Answer (score 3):

One can also derive the really neat expression for this sort of thing:

$$
[a_1\otimes a_2,b_1\otimes b_2]=
[a_1,b_1]\otimes\{a_2,b_2\}+\{a_1,b_1\}\otimes[a_2,b_2]\
$$
and
$$
\{a_1\otimes a_2,b_1\otimes b_2\}=
\{a_1,b_1\}\otimes\{a_2,b_2\}+[a_1,b_1]\otimes[a_2,b_2]\
$$

Which can be recursively applied to the right hand side if you have more tensor products, for example if $a_1$ and $b_1$ are also tensor products of something else:

$$
[a_1,b_1] = [a_{11}\otimes a_{12},b_{11}\otimes b_{12}]
$$
and
$$
\{a_1,b_1\} = \{a_{11}\otimes a_{12},b_{11}\otimes b_{12}\}
$$

If you prefer to write commutators of tensor products as tensor products of commutators.